DB@ SQL Dynamic SQL using Values/Into with marker
trying to execute dynamic sql using values/into with marker inside select
    DCL-DS GroupDS;
   wGrpSOAId  Packed(7:0);
   wAttach    Packed(7:0);
   wNotAttach Packed(7:0);
End-Ds;   

wFrom1 = 'FROM TBL1.ADD';
//Build 'Group counts' SQL statements
wSQL1 = 'SELECT ID, ' +
         ' sum(Case when status=''A'' then 1 else 0 end), ' +
         ' sum(Case when status=''R'' then 1 else 0 end) ' +
         ' INTO :GroupDS '
         + %Trim(wFrom1) +
         ' WHERE ID = ? ' +
         ' GROUP BY ID'''

Exec Sql prepare @GrpSql from :wSQL1;
Exec Sql Execute @GrpSql using :wID;

Is it possible to put this query inside values/into?
something like VALUES(wSQL1 or the actual select) INTO ?,?,?
I have not found any examples of this or do I need to use cursor?

SELECT ... INTO can not be dynamically prepared...
However, VALUES ... INTO can be.
This should be close...
DCL-DS GroupDS;
   wGrpSOAId  Packed(7:0);
   wAttach    Packed(7:0);
   wNotAttach Packed(7:0);
End-Ds;   

wFrom1 = 'FROM TBL1.ADD';
//Build 'Group counts' SQL statements
wSQL1 = 'VALUES (' +
         ' SELECT ID, ' +
         ' sum(Case when status=''A'' then 1 else 0 end), ' +
         ' sum(Case when status=''R'' then 1 else 0 end) ' +
         + %Trim(wFrom1) +
         ' WHERE ID = ? ' +
         ' GROUP BY ID' +
         ' ) INTO ?';

Exec Sql prepare @GrpSql from :wSQL1;
//should be checking SQLSTATE/SQLCODE
Exec Sql Execute @GrpSql using :wID, :GroupDS;
//should be checking SQLSTATE/SQLCODE

